# Загрузка ios Приложения на TestFlight

Tags: ios, xamarin, mobile-development, apple

Всем привет, есть приложение для ios.

Перечитал уже много литературы но так и не понял, как мне его загрузить на платформу testflight ? 
Для тестирования, читал что нужно подтвержать через Xcode но так и ничего не получилось пока.

Скиньте ссылку либо объясните пожалуйста подробно что делать.

Answer (score 0):

Почитай на сайте developer.apple.com

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight/DistributingYourAppUsingTestFlight.html